# Slices JSON array and connect 2 datapairs randomly -- EASY or Difficult?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an example json file with n / unlimited users

```
[{
    "fname": "Hubert",
    "lname": "Maier",
    "email": "h@m.com"},
    {
        "fname": "Hubert1",...........
```

now i want to connect the users randomly into pairs so each user gets another user as pair partner.
then print out the pairs in the console

restricted for me: cannot be pair with yourself and if uneven number print the user out who didnt got a match.

which method would be the best ?
i tried to come up with a solution i javascript, after playing around alot nothing really good happened :)

atleast i managed to read the external json file :)

```
let readJSON = function (file) {
    let json = {}
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      global: false,
      url: file,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        json = data
      }
    })
    return json
  }
  
  let x= readJSON('data.json')
  console.table(x)
```

Comment: Could you please specify what you understand as "randomly into pairs"? Do you want to iterate over the array and just "pair" the following entry with the current or do you want to choose a random person from the array to connect to the current?

Comment: it should pick a random person. so you have a pool of like 50 ppl and the result should be 25 pairs which will be randomly picked, not 1with2 3with4 and so on more like  pair: 1,6 // 4,7 // 22,33 // and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below. (unmatched element will be appended as last element)

```
// return next() function which will return random element
const getRandom = array => {
    const data = [...array];
    return () => {
        const length = data.length;
        const randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random()) * length) - 1;
        return data.splice(randomIndex,1)[0];
    }
}
// shuffle array using next() function
const shuffle = array => {
    const next = getRandom(array);
    return array.map(() => next());
}
// use Array.reduce to subgroup array
const subgroup = (array, numberInSubArray) => {
    return array.reduce((acc, element) => {
        const lastGroup = acc[acc.length - 1]
        lastGroup.length === numberInSubArray ?
        acc.push([element]) :
        lastGroup.push(element);
        return acc;
    },[[]])
}


const persons = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','x'];
const shuffled = shuffle(persons);
console.log(subgroup(shuffled,2))
// [ [ 'd', 'h' ], [ 'a', 'f' ], [ 'b', 'g' ], [ 'c', 'x' ], [ 'e' ] ]
```